# ajax await async:false Difference

Tags: javascript, ajax, function, async-await, synchronization

First of all, I am not good at English, so please understand if my writing is weird.

We found two ways when converting from ajax asynchronous calls to synchronization.

1. async: false
2. await

It shows the same result, but I would like to know the difference between these two modes of operation.

```
function callAjax(url) {
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        caches: false,
        async: false,
        success: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        },
        failed: function(e) {
            ajaxFail(e);
        }
    });
}
```

```
async function ca(url) {


    await $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        caches: false,
        success: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        },
        failed: function(e) {
            ajaxFail(e);
        }
    });
}
```

I don't know how to directly identify the fundamental part. I don't even know if I wrote English properly. I'm sorry.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: You should never do `async: false` - it's deprecated and makes for poor UX

Comment: 2nd function is recommended method for the asynchronous call.

Answer (score 0):

Both functions perform AJAX POST requests, but the first one is synchronous (not recommended), and there is a typo in the error callback name. The second one is asynchronous (preferred) and has the correct error callback name.
Also there are a lot of differences between 2 functions.

1. Handling Asynchronous Behavior

- In the 1st function (callAjax), async: false is used. This makes the AJAX request synchronous, meaning that the execution of the script will be blocked until the request is complete. This is generally discouraged in modern web development because synchronous requests can lead to poor user experience and may cause the browser to become unresponsive during the request.
- In the 2nd function (ca), the async option is not explicitly set, so it defaults to true. This means the AJAX request is asynchronous, and the script execution will not be blocked. Modern best practices recommend using asynchronous requests to avoid blocking the main thread.

2. Handling Data:

- Both functions are sending POST requests with the contentType set to JSON and are sending JSON data in the request body using JSON.stringify(data).

3. Handling Success and Failure:

- Both functions have success and failure callback functions. However, the names of the callback functions differ. In the first function, the success callback is named success, and the failure callback is named failed. In the second function, the success callback is also named success, and the failure callback is named failed.

4. Typo in the First Function:

- There is a typo in the first function: failed should be error in the options object. The correct event name for handling errors in jQuery AJAX is error, not failed. The corrected version is as you mentioned:

```
failed: function(e) {
    ajaxFail(e);
}
```